# Querying the mapped value of map(flatmap(provider(task 'processDebugGoogleServices', has completed is not supported android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore cloud database not integrating in Android. Can anyone please help ?

I have followed standard documentation as per firebase but its not working. Please help me for getting it fixed.[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycN1N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiBHl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbAbo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/716et.png)

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Show us the code as text, no image, please. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.